# Run Linux service from java code causing service: command not found

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

I want to run Linux service from my Java code. I tried to do it in many ways. Even writing .sh script that executes service  start, but I keep getting following error:
/opt/scripts/service-stop.sh: line 3: service: command not found

Here my .sh script

```
echo "Service name: $1"
echo "Start args: $2"
service $1 start $2
```

Java code:

```
private void executeCommandAndWait(String... args) {
    ProcessBuilder pb= new ProcessBuilder().command(args);
    Process proc = pb.start();
}

        executeCommandAndWait("/bin/bash", "-c", "/opt/scripts/service-start.sh", srvName, "some-arg");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'service' is a system call, and needs to be run by a sudo user.  I'm guessing that it isn't in the PATH for the Java process/user.  You might get away with using its full path:

```
/$PATH_TO_SERVICE/service $1 start $2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `systemctl` in your bash script:

I'm not sure how you pass args to it (maybe [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/728951/systemd-giving-my-service-multiple-arguments#728962)  will help), but the basic is:

```
systemctl start <service>
```

or

```
sudo systemctl start <service>
```

The Arch wiki has some [very decent documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd) :)